# How do I use an instance variable assigned in a helper_method from a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been drying up one of our controllers in our rails 2.3 app, and I've run up against a problem using an instance variable assigned in a helper_method.  Originally, the situation was like this:

```
home_controller.rb:
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end

  def popular
    @popular_questions = PopularQuestion.paginate :page => params[:page],
                                                  <some complex query>
  end
end

home_helper.rb:
module HomeHelper
  def render_popular_questions
    @popular_questions = PopularQuestion.paginate :page => 1, 
                                                  <some complex query>
    render :partial => 'popular'
  end
end

home/index.html.haml
-cached do
  .popular=render_popular_questions

home/popular.html.haml
=render :partial => 'popular'

home/_popular.html.haml
-if @popular_questions.length > 0
  <show stuff>
```

hitting either / or /popular showed the appropriate box of popular questions.

Now, since the query was pretty much duplicated, and since paginate will use the correct page by default, I refactored this as:

```
home_controller.rb:
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :get_popular_questions

  def index
  end

  def popular
    get_popular_questions
  end

  private

  def get_popular_questions
    @popular_questions = PopularQuestion.paginate :page => params[:page],
                                                  <some complex query>
  end
end

home_helper.rb:
module HomeHelper
  def render_popular_questions
    get_popular_questions
    render :partial => 'popular'
  end
end
```

now when I go to /, I get

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.length
```

being raised in line 1 of home/_popular.html.haml

It seems that variables set from within helper_methods called from within helpers aren't accessible to the template.  Have I made a mistake somewhere?  If not, how do I use an instance variable assigned in a helper_method from a helper?

Comment: it's really bad practice to make partials depend on instance variable, you should always send them local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass them as parameters and local-variables:

```
home_controller.rb:
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :get_popular_questions

  def index
  end

  def popular
    @popular_questions = get_popular_questions
  end

  private

  def get_popular_questions
    # remember that the final statement of a method is also the return-value
    PopularQuestion.paginate :page => params[:page],
                                              <some complex query>
  end
end

home_helper.rb:
module HomeHelper
  def render_popular_questions
    questions = get_popular_questions
    render :partial => 'popular', :locals => {:questions => questions}
  end
end
```

now in your partial, use "questions" instead of "@popular_questions" 
Just make sure that the main template for "popular" also need to populate this local variable too.

Comment: I'm torn here... you've given a good answer which solves the problem and teaches me about best practise, but I was really hoping for an answer that would help me understand why it didn't work - how instance variables on a controller gets passed to a view, and why they should be settable from a helper but not a helper_method.

I guess I'll wait and see whether a more technical answer comes along - but in the mean time I wanted you to know that I think yours is a great answer!

Comment: The quick answer is that the reason it doesn't work is that you are using controllers and helpers in a way they were never expected to work. Rendering partials should rightly be done only in a controller. All the code that is set up to correctly pass through, say @-variables to the view is set up in the controller... not the helper. Therefore I'm unsurprised that it doesn't work when you try to use it in a helper. You are asking me why it doesn't work, and the best answer is "because it's not supposed to".

Comment: None-the-less, you can still do what you're doing - by setting it up using local variables instead of relying on the controller-only @-variable practice.